# SQL Error (1064): check the manual corresponds your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 44

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to execute below query and getting error [Window Title]
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 44

```sql
WITH Master_CTE (`id`,`range`, `review`, `validate`)
AS (SELECT 1 as `id`,
  '<1' AS `range`,
  0 AS `review`,
  0 AS `validate`
UNION
SELECT 2 as id,
  '1-4' AS `range`,
  0 AS `review`,
  0 AS `validate`
UNION
SELECT 3 as `id`,
  '4-8' AS `range`,
  0 AS `review`,
  0 AS `validate`
UNION
SELECT 4 as `id`,
  '8-24' AS `range`,
  0 AS `review`,
  0 AS `validate`
UNION
SELECT 5 as `id`,
  '>24' AS `range`,
  0 AS `review`,
  0 AS `validate`)
SELECT
  mc.id,
  IFNULL(t.time_taken, mc.range) AS `range`,
  IFNULL(t.review, mc.review) AS `review`,
  IFNULL(t.validate, mc.validate) AS `validate`
FROM Master_CTE mc LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT m.range AS `range`, 
       Ifnull((SELECT Count(r.req_status) AS `reviewcount` 
               FROM   T1 r 
               WHERE  r.req_status = 'READY_FOR_REV' 
                      AND r.time_taken = m.range 
               GROUP  BY r.time_taken), 0) `review`, 
       Ifnull((SELECT Count(s.req_status) AS `reviewcount `
               FROM   T1 s 
               WHERE  s.req_status = 'READY_FOR_VAL' 
                      AND s.time_taken = m.range
               GROUP  BY s.time_taken), 0) `validate`
FROM   V1 m 
GROUP  BY m.range) t
```

The Table names are replaced with T1 and view name with V1.

The sub query after LEFT OUTER JOIN works fine when i run individually, but when i club them together it started giving error as shown in title.

Please help

Comment: I guess there is a `UNION` missing after `  0 AS 'validate')` and before `SELECT mc.id,` ?

Comment: Nope, I have used WITH clause (WITH Master_CTE) and joining the output of WITH clause with the subquery that is specified after LEFT OUTER JOIN  keyword

Comment: Right. Just noticed one more thing: `reviewcount ` appears once with a space afterwards that should not be there. I am pretty sure this is not the main problem, though, as it should not trigger a syntax error.

Comment: What MariaDB version is this? MariaDB introduced CTEs using `WITH` in MariaDB 10.2.1 https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/with/

Comment: Version that i am using latest one - 10.3

Answer (score 0):

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is missing the join-condition, i.e. something like `ON t.range=mc.range` or whatever your join condition should be right at the end.

Comment: Did that help you?